# Declaring an object in JavaScript for later use - null or {}?

Tags: javascript

Simple question, What is the best practise, should I declare JavaScript objects, that will not be initialized until some later stage, with `null` or `{}`?

Comment: `var myObjForLater = {};`

Comment: `{}` is essentially short for `new Object()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends.  If you just want to declare it early because you know it is "hoisted" to the beginning of the function anyway, and will initialize a few lines down below, then just use

```
var foo;
```

which makes `foo` `undefined`.  Otherwise, if you need to do anything with `foo` being an object before your initialization, then it will be better to use

```
var foo = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the object literal `{}`. That way, you can immediately start using it as an object, when you have to, instead of having to initialize it again as an object, later on.

So:

```
var myObj = {};
// loads of code
myObj.someProperty = 'foobar';
```

Instead of:

```
var myObj;        // undefined, or:
var myObj = null; // null
// loads of code
var myObj = {};
myObj.someProperty = 'foobar';
```

Makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: Can't see that's any "better" than `var x; ... x = {someProperty:'foobar'};`. Of course initialising to `null` is pointless unless it is used for some logic before being replaced by some other value.

Comment: Hm, that's a fair point, @RobG. You're making me think: Not initializing the object might be a good idea, depending on if you want `undefined` exceptions when the object isn't initialized yet...

Comment: To me it's just a matter of what is more readable in the context of the rest of the code. Likely I'd initialise with an empty object to make it obvious what *x* was, but the name should do that too. It would depend on how properties were to be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{};` as it makes your code more compact, and more readable. You may try it like this:

```
var x = {};
```

By this way you can start using x as an object without initializing it again.

Also to add

```
var x= {} //This is an object literal

var y= new Object() //This is the object constructor
```

Also `{}` syntax is shorter, neater,readable, and allows you to instantly populate the object inline